# Can anyone tell me what is this error in flutter when I am trying to add syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer package

Tags: flutter, dart

When I add  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer package in yaml file I am getting the below error. can anyone tell me what is that error states ?
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer-20.2.48-beta/lib/src/common/pdfviewer_plugin.dart:21:23: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
CancelableOperation<Uint8List?>? _nativeImage;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer-20.2.48-beta/lib/src/common/pdfviewer_plugin.dart:24:37: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.

Answer (score 1):

After adding package, application should be compiled again.

Try running a command in terminal.

```
flutter run -d [device id]
```

UPDATE:
Also try to:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
```

in a file where you are using syncfusion components.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was also resolved for me by upgrading to the latest Flutter version (as of 22 October 2022).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade flutter to the latest version. This issue was solved after I upgraded to version 3.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Might not the easiest decision but upgrading flutter, mine was 2.10.3 to 3.7.11 solved the problem.