# How to solve GoogleFontsFile file, Uint8List bytes error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

When i install the google fonts package and i import it, i run the code but i get a particular error that make me to be confuse.

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_fonts-4.0.3/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:317:42: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
bool _isFileSecure(GoogleFontsFile file, Uint8List bytes) {
^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add `import 'dart:typed_data'` to `google_fonts_base.dart`

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73638843/can-anyone-tell-me-what-is-this-error-in-flutter-when-i-am-trying-to-add-syncfus)